# How to get list of multiple values from select2 sent via ajax in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, forms, jquery-select2

I have a select2 with multiple values that you can select. List of values is sent but never received. This is my code:

HTML:

```
   <input type="hidden" id="servicio" name="ides[]"/>
```

JQUERY:

```
    $("#servicio").select2({
        placeholder: "",
        multiple: "multiple"
    });

   $("body").on("click", ".btnPag", function () {

    var data = $("#formBuscar").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "sendList.action",
        data: data,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (msg) {}
    });
    return false;
    });
```

JAVA:

```
 I have tried these, but none seem to work:
     String[] ides;
     int[] ides;
     List<Integer> ides;
     List<String> ides;
```

The list is sent but is not received in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post the recieving java code.
If you have access to an `HTTPServletRequest request`, 
then you can use `request.getParameterValues()` , which will return an array of values, giving you access to all the different values that appear on the same parameter.

I also suggest that you use your browser's developer tools to verify that the js plugin indeed sends multiple values for the same parameter as expected.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html for String[] getParameterValues(String name)